# Mobx computed doesn't work

Tags: javascript, mobx

I'm using mobx 4.2.0
When I try a use a computed property, I got some problem
Code like this:

```js
class ODOM {
  constructor(props) {
    console.log('how many times')
  }
  @observable speed = 0
  @action change(obj) {
    console.log(obj)
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(item => {
      this[item] = obj[item]
    })
  }
  @computed get velocity() {
    console.log('entry')
    return this.speed*60*60/1000
  }
}
const model = new ODOM()
let total = 0
setInterval(() => {
  model.change({
    speed: ++total
  })
}, 3000)
export default model
```

the console 'entry' only run once
What's the problem with those code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computed re-calculation is only triggered by mobx in components that directly use this property in the render function and these react components must be annotated with `@observer` attribute.

otherwise use non computed/normal properties or cache the value yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Your computed has to be observed in order for it to be re-computed when the observables it depends on changes.

[This example](http://jsbin.com/boroxineqa/edit?js,console) uses an [autorun](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/autorun.html) to show the behavior:

```
class ODOM {
  @observable speed = 0

  @action change(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(item => {
      this[item] = obj[item]
    })
  }

  @computed get velocity() {
    console.log('entry')
    return this.speed*60*60/1000
  }
}

const model = new ODOM()
let total = 0
setInterval(() => {
  model.change({
    speed: ++total
  })
}, 1000);

autorun(() => {
  console.log(model.velocity);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mate.

Answer (score 0):

if @withRouter is under @observer will make @observer,@computed failure
like this (wrong):

```js
@observer 
// @ts-ignore
@withRouter
```

you need to write like this (correct):

```js
// @ts-ignore 
@withRouter
@observer
```

Answer (score -3):

I found the problem.Cause the observer doesn't use correctly.